# Looking for information on how to construct an SQL query with multiple mappings

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have a primary table with two additional linked tables, each relationship has a mapping table, I've obfuscated this and simplified the scenario.

| Person |
| --- |
| id |
| name |

| Location |
| --- |
| id |
| name |

| Person_Location |
| --- |
| person_id |
| location_id |

| Nationality |
| --- |
| id |
| name |

| Person_Nationality |
| --- |
| person_id |
| nationality_id |

I'm looking to query each person and return one row for each related table

Person Name, Location Name, Nationilty Name

Some of the related tables may not be populated and I'd like the row returned but an empty value representing where the data is missing.

I've got a query with INNER JOINS for Person, Location and Person_Location mapping table but when I add additional joins for the Nationality mapping table, this returns many more rows than exists? I'm happy with a single set of joins but repeating this for additional one is not bearing fruit. I can't seem to find any examples of how to do this although I may not be using the correct approach.

```
SELECT p.name, lo.name as location, na.name as nationality
FROM person p
INNER JOIN person_location pl ON p.id = pl.person_id
INNER JOIN location lo ON pl.location_id = lo.id
INNER JOIN person_nationality pn ON p.id = pn.person_id
INNER JOIN nationality na ON pm.nationality_id = na.id
```

Comment: 1) Those should be LEFT OUTER JOINs if you want to include all `person` records regardless if they should have an entry in `nationality` or `location`. 2) Your last join's condition references alias `pm` but it should be `pn`. I suspect that's a typo in the question otherwise it would throw an error. Other than that, your query looks correct. We would need to see sample data and desired results to help further if you are still experiencing unexpected results.

Comment: If a person has more than one location and more than one nationality, show an example of what you want

Comment: "...but when I add additional joins for the Nationality mapping table, this returns many more rows..." -- Of course, that's how joins work in relational algebra.

Comment: Is your intention that a person should have a single row in `person_location` and `person_nationality`? If so, this is the wrong way to structure your data. If not, which record do you want to return for your _"single row"_? Using correlated sub-queries seems to be covering up an unintended condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use two scalar subqueries to get the result you want. For example:

```
select p.name,
  (select l.name from location l join person_location pl 
     on pl.location_id = l.id and pl.person_id = p.id limit 1) as location,
  (select n.name from nationality n join person_nationality pn 
     on pn.nationality_id = n.id and pn.person_id = p.id limit 1) as nationality  
from person p
```

Comment: That's what I was looking for, I've used something like this decades ago but that knowledge was long lost and I didn't know its name to go looking either. Thanks.